# Opening ODS file using System.IO.Packaging C#

Tags: c#, .net, compression

I want to get the content.xml in *.ods. I know this can be achieve by using the APIs of DotNetZip. Instead, I would like to do this by using the System.IO.Package of microsoft.

Tried the code below but can't get the files inside.

```
using (Package package = ZipPackage.Open(@"C:\Book1.ods", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
     // get files?
}
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks!